# Getting the first td text from class of another td

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that contain a `<td>` column with class name and first `<td>` column that contain `qty`. I am iterating the `name` column for a particular `name`, if found I want to get the `qty` still on the same row:

```
$('.ordertable .name').each(function(){
                            $this = $(this);
                        var $data = $this.html();
                            alert($data);
                        if($data == chkitemValue){
                                qtyclicked++;
                                //gQty = $this.parent().siblings('td').eq(0).text(qtyclicked);
                                //gQty = $('td:first', this).text();
                                gQty = $(this).find('td:first').text();
                                alert(gQty);
                                flag = true;
                            }else{
                                flag = false;
                                alert(flag);
                        }

                    });
```

I have tried all that I know - can someone point to the right direction for me? Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="ordertable">
 <tr><td>1</td><td class="name">John</td><td>manager</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td class="name">Mike</td><td>director</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td class="name">hinn</td><td>assist.manager</td></tr>
</table>
```

that is if i get the name john i should be able to get the first  value which is 1(one) and set it

Comment: put a fiddle with the html or insert the html in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery siblings method to get a collection of all the siblings (go figure).  If quantity is your first column, you can use the line below in your .each call.

```
$('.ordertable .name').each(function(index, item){

    var $item = $(item);

    if ($item.text() == 'Mike')
        alert('The quantity is ' + $($item.siblings()[0]).text() );

});
```

[Here's a fiddle that alerts the quantity of the row with name = 'Mike'](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/MLByP/)

Comment: I linked a fiddle in my answer.  What kind of code are you looking for?

Comment: if the table column is dynamic how can it be done to get the columns text